# Retrieve the name of the UIImage at a specific point in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage

I'm having trouble getting my head around this; I've looked around for answers on here but either nothing directly applies to my question or I just can't make sense of it. (I am relatively new to this, so apologise if there is an obvious answer.)

I am inserting an array of UIImages (contained within a UIImageView) into a UIScrollView. **I can programmatically scroll to points in the ScrollView, but I need to be able to identify by name which image is currently being shown after scrolling (so I can compare the image to one in another ScrollView).**

How I have created my arrays and added the images to the ImageView and ScrollView is below.

---

ViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

...

// Store the names as strings
stringArr = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"img0",
                       @"img1",
                       @"img2",
                       @"img3",
                       nil] retain];

// Add images to array
dataArr = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
    [UIImage imageNamed:[stringArr objectAtIndex:0]],
    [UIImage imageNamed:[stringArr objectAtIndex:1]],
    [UIImage imageNamed:[stringArr objectAtIndex:2]],
    [UIImage imageNamed:[stringArr objectAtIndex:3]],
    nil] retain];

// Use a dictionary to try and make it possible to retrieve an image by name
dataDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:dataArr forKeys:stringArr];

i = 0;
currentY = 0.0f;

// Set up contents of scrollview
// I'm adding each of the four images four times, in a random order
for (imageCount = 0; imageCount < 4; imageCount++) {
    // Add images from the array to image views inside the scroll view.
    for (UIImage *image in reelDictionary)
    {
        int rand = arc4random_uniform(4);

        UIImage *images = [dataArr objectAtIndex:rand];
        imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:images];
        imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        // I have tried to use this to tag each individual image
        imgView.tag = i;
        i++;

        CGRect rect = imgView.frame;
        rect.origin.y = currentY;
        imgView.frame = rect;
        currentY += imgView.frame.size.height;
        [scrollReel1 addSubview:reel1_imgView];
        [reel1_imgView release];
    }
}
scrollReel.contentSize = CGSizeMake(100, currentY);
[self.view addSubview:scrollReel];

...

}
```

---

This is how I am working out where I am in the ScrollView (currentOffset), and also exactly which image I need to retrieve (symbolNo). **The value of symbolNo is correct when I test it, but I am unsure how to use the value with respect to image name retrieval.**

```
NSInteger currentOffset = scrollReel.contentOffset.y;
NSInteger symbolNo = (currentOffset / 100) + 1;
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. The UIImage object doesn't store its name once it's loaded.

You could get around this by using the `tag` property on the image views if all your images have numerical names.

Otherwise you'll need to find a new way to model your data.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need the reverse mapping of what you had. Here is a quick and dirty solution

```
NSMutableDictionary *indexToImageMap = [NSMutableDictionary new];
for (imageCount = 0; imageCount < 4; imageCount++) {
// Add images from the array to image views inside the scroll view.
for (UIImage *image in reelDictionary)
{
    int rand = arc4random_uniform(4);

    UIImage *images = [dataArr objectAtIndex:rand];
    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:images];
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    // I have tried to use this to tag each individual image
    imgView.tag = i;
    i++;
    [indexToImageMap setObject:imgView forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i];

    CGRect rect = imgView.frame;
    rect.origin.y = currentY;
    imgView.frame = rect;
    currentY += imgView.frame.size.height;
    [scrollReel1 addSubview:reel1_imgView];
    [reel1_imgView release];
}

}
```

And to look it up you do

```
NSInteger currentOffset = scrollReel.contentOffset.y;
NSInteger symbolNo = (currentOffset / 100) + 1;
NSImage *image = [indexToImageMap objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:symbolNo]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass image view and add imageName property. if i understand what you are asking this should work.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myImageView : UIImageView
{
    __strong NSString *imageName;
}

@property (strong) NSString *imageName;

@end



#import "myImageView.h"

@implementation myImageView
@synthesize imageName;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

then use a dictionary to keep everything instead of array + dictionary.

```
myImageView *imgView1 = [[myImageView alloc] init];
[imgView1 setImageName:@"image_name_here"];
[imgView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name_here"]];

NSMutableDictionary *dicti = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dicti setObject:imgView1 forKey:@"image_name_here_1"];
[dicti setObject:imgView2 forKey:@"image_name_here_2"];
[dicti setObject:imgView... forKey:@"image_name_here_..."];
```

when you find the imageView you can search image in dictionary. because you know name of the imageView now.